# Getting Cron Daemon emails, but no user has crontab

Tags: cron, email

Users on a server of mine are getting mails in `/var/spool/mail` from Cron Daemon runs but when I check the user's crontab there is nothing there?

```
From munin@example.localdomain  Tue Nov  2 15:00:12 2021
Return-Path: <munin@example.localdomain>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@example.localdomain
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <munin@example.localdomain>
To: root@example.localdomain
Subject: Cron <munin@example>  /usr/bin/munin-cron
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=292949>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/997>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=root>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/lib/munin>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=munin>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=munin>
Date: Tue,  2 Nov 2021 15:00:12 +0100 (CET)
Status: RO
```

```
$ sudo crontab -umunin
no crontab for munin
```

How do I find out where this cron is executed so I can stop it (it's just producing error messages so I want to remove it)

Comment: Is the job started from `/etc/crontab` or from a file in `/etc/cron.d/`?

Comment: Are there any messages in the log files? `grep CROND /var/log/cron` on a REL-type system.

Answer (score 1):

The messages are from `/usr/bin/munin-cron`.

You can read `man -k munin` and `man munin-cron`.

Why are you running `munin-cron`? Managing an Apache server? Read `https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/tools-munin`.

You can find out which package provided it:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/munin-cron
```

and consider reconfiguring or removing that package, but there may be side effects.